# animationend starts next function, next functions animationend starts twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I'm doing some interactive animation using HTML, CSS, and Javascript+Jquery.

I have several animations that I want to chain. So when first animation is done, the next starts, and so on.

The first function is triggered by a click:

```
function stepOne() {
    console.log(" stepOne ran");
    $('#myObject').attr('class', 'animation1');
    $(".animation1").on("animationend", stepTwo);
}

function stepTwo() {
    console.log("stepTwo ran");
    $("#myObject").removeClass("animation1");
    $("#myObject").addClass("animation2");
    $("#scene").addClass("zoomAnimation");
    $("#scene").on("animationend", stepThree);


    function stepThree() {
```

// insert some exciting code here
            console.log("crashes");
        }

I can see in the console log, that it runs stepTwo and stepThree at the same time, and then Stepthree again when the animation actually ends. How do I prevent it from running stepThree together with stepTwo? This is only an issue if I run it in sequence. If i jump directly to stepTwo there's not issue.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I found a work around.

Adding a tiny delay on the animationend listener at the end of the function seems to be the solution. 
So it becomes

```
function stepTwo() {
    console.log("stepTwo ran");
    $("#myObject").removeClass("animation1");
    $("#myObject").addClass("animation2");
    $("#scene").addClass("zoomAnimation");
    setTimeout(function () {
    $(".zoomAnimation").on("animationend", stepThree);
   }, 20);
```

}

```
function stepThree() {
$(".zoomAnimation").off("animationend", stepThree);
```

}

and so on. Might not be the best solution, and may cost me problems down the road, but it seems to be correct.